# Using Facebook API. Retrieve 0 events through Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook api to retrieve /me/events  but it returns a blank json array. When I make the same call in a browser using a different access token, my events return....what is going on??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacked the permission for user_events....